# Jquery/Javascript external file is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, external

can anyone catch why my javascript/jquery is not working? Thanks!!!

HTML (employment.php)

```
        <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resume_script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <title>Employment</title>

    <body onload="load">
        <h1>Employment History</h1>
        <button type="button" id="add_job">+</button>
        <form action="result.php">
            Start Date: <input type="text" id="start_date"> End Date: <input type="text" id="end_date"> <br><br>
            Description:<br> <textarea id="position"></textarea> <br>

            <div id="add_form"></div>

            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    <div id="footer">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="position.php">Position</a></li>
                <li><a href="employment.php">Employment</a></li>
                <li><a href="resume.php">Resume</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

JAVASCRIPT (resume_script.js)

```
    $(function(){
        alert("test");
        $('#add_job').click(addJob);

    });

    function load(){
        alert("Page is loaded");
    }

    function addJob(){
        alert('test');
        $('Start Date: <input type="text" name="start_date"> End Date: <input type="text" name="end_date"> <br><br>').appendTo('#add_job')
    }
```

I am not getting any of my alerts

---

I figured it out, it was just a small syntax error. Thank you guys for all the help and recommending me to use the console!

Comment: You are missing `(` and `)` in `addJob` function.

Comment: Is the last line missing some brackets?

Comment: What do you mean I am missing the ( and )? Thanks

Comment: It should be: `$('<input type="text" name="start_date"> End Date: <input type="text" name="end_date"><br><br>').appendTo('#add_job')`

Comment: User your browser's console and look for the error messages.

Comment: I fixed that ( and ) problem, but it seems like it is not reading my javascript file. I'll try the console now

Comment: Look at the net tab on the console. Do you have a 404?

Comment: In my console I get these errors `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; resume_script.js:13
Uncaught ReferenceError: load is not defined employment.php:10
onload"`

Comment: I actually get the page to run, but the javascript is just not working. Thank you guys so much for the help. I appreciate it.

Comment: You shouldn't use onload, but when you do it, it should be `onload="load();"`, use jquery ready instead (or the shortcut that you already use)

Answer (score 2):

```
 function addJob(){
        alert('test');
        $'Start Date: <input type="text" name="start_date"> End Date: <input type="text" name="end_date"> <br><br>'.appendTo('#add_job')
 }
```

Should be:

```
function addJob(){
        alert('test');
        $('Start Date: <input type="text" name="start_date"> End Date: <input type="text" name="end_date"> <br><br>').appendTo('#add_job');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that error! I just made that change, and it seems like its still not working.

Comment: This http://jsfiddle.net/m4S9t/ seems to work for me? What do you mean by "is not working"?

Comment: Hmmmm, what do you think the problem is? My resume_script is in the same folder as my php file. I am sure the problem has to do with the external, it seems like it is not reading my javascript file at all. And I can't seem to catch why.

Comment: Probably the file is cached and you still get the old file?